# Register_Sidebar overwriting itself and doesn't exist in global $wp_registered_sidebars;

Tags: functions, widgets, sidebar, register-sidebar

I have Dynamic sidebars that are generated based on terms of a taxonomy that were created.

**CLASS EXCERPT:**

```
public function __construct() {
    add_action('widgets_init', array($this, 'checkForActiveSidebarAndMenu'));   
}
public function checkForActiveSidebarAndMenu() {
    //global $wp_registered_sidebars;
    //print_r($wp_registered_sidebars);
    $terms = get_terms(array('taxonomy'=>'minisite','hide_empty'=>false));
    print_r($terms);
    foreach($terms as $term) {
        $this->registerSidebars($term->term_id);
        //$this->registerMenu($term->term_id);
        update_term_meta($term->term_id, 'sidebar_active', '1');
        //update_term_meta($term->term_id, 'menu_active', '1');
    }
}
public function registerSidebars($mini_site_id) {
    // Register main content sidebar, [MINISITENAME]_[TERMID]_HOMEPAGE
    // Register right aligned sidebar, [MINISITENAME]_[TERMID]_RIGHT_SIDEBAR
    $mini_site_name = get_term($mini_site_id, 'minisite');
    $mini_site_name = $mini_site_name->slug;
    $sidebar_name = $mini_site_name . '_' . $mini_site_id;
    $args = array(
        'id'=>$sidebar_name . '_HOMEPAGE',
        'name'=>$sidebar_name . ' HOMEPAGE'
    );
    register_sidebar($args);
    //var_dump($sidebar);
    $args = array(
        'id'=>$sidebar_name . '_RIGHT_SIDEBAR',
        'name'=>$sidebar_name . ' RIGHT SIDEBAR'
    );
    register_sidebar($args);
}
```

This function registers the sidebar. The query array in "get_terms" will change.

This is my second function that I've written as initially I was under the impression that sidebars only need to be registered once, not every single 'widgets_init'

The above code creates the sidebar every time widgets_init runs which means that I can populate my sidebar with widgets, refresh and the new sidebar would be there and the old one gone.

What am I doing wrong? I want to be able to register a dynamic sidebar and for it to stay until I unregister it.

Additional:

- The class is fine and the methods are executing as they should.
- The taxonomy "minisite" is my taxonomy and it works fine, it loads as priority 0 on 'init' to allow for widgets_init to run with that taxonomy correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was simple and made me feel tremendously stupid.
90% of the issues I could find remotely similar to my issue were all issues relating to the casing. Throughout this whole process I overlooked the "_HOMEPAGE" and "_RIGHT_SIDEBAR" in my IDs.

Those should be lowercase.

> id - Sidebar id - Must be all in lowercase, with no spaces (default is a numeric auto-incremented ID). If you do not set the id argument value, you will get E_USER_NOTICE messages in debug mode, starting with version 4.2.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar#Parameters